# Should I install Angular for every Node version?

Tags: node.js, angular, nvm

I have a problem when switching from a Node.js version to another one (with the command `nvm use nodeVersion`).

For example when I use **node 12.0.0**, that I already used to develop a little application, I'm able to run the command `ng version`.
If I switch, for example, to **node 12.11.0**, when I run the command `ng version` I get the error **bash: /c/Program Files/nodejs/ng: No such file or directory**.

This makes me think that I have to re-install Angular for every version of Node I use, doing something like this:

1. `nvm use nodeVersion`
2. `npm install -g @angular/cli version`

Am I right? Or there is something I didn't get?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use different node versions?

Comment: Yes, if you use nvm, your global packages will be kept separate for each version, so you will to have to reinstall them for each version.

Comment: @DownloadPizza because I use different Angular version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

each node version has each library folder, so you need to install what you want for each node version because some libraries are depending on the node version.

I recommend you if you are using windows 10, Install Ubuntu Terminal from Microsoft Store, It can solves many problems

Comment: Thank for the explenation. Now I got it :)